# Plugin en Perl para SpamAssassin

Tags: email, plugin, perl, preg-match

¿Algún ejemplo para realizar un *plugin* en Perl e integrarlo a un fichero de configuración? O, ¿dónde hay un tutorial que lo explique? Gracias.

```
package MyPlugin;

use Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin;
our @ISA = qw(Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin);


sub new {
    my ( $class, $mailsa ) = @_;
    
    $class = ref($class) || $class;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new($mailsa);
    bless( $self, $class );
    
    $self->register_eval_rule("check_for_from_is_not_reply_to_whitelist");
    
    return $self;
 }
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]



-----------------------

Te recomiendo poner tu código con un [snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%C3%A9-es-stack-snippet) para obtener respuestas más enfocadas a tu problema.

Comment: Pero sabes a lo que me refiero o no?

Comment: definitivamente no, nunca he programado en perl

Comment: No me queda claro. ¿Necesitarías que se filtrara el correo como hace con el servicio SpamAssassin pero en perl?

Comment: Si, así mismo. Realizar plugin en Perl.